# How to make the neo4j web console display relationships in 'rows' mode

Tags: neo4j

Imagine I run this generic query in the stock neo4j web interface:

```
match(n {pk:"ddd"})-[r]->(m) return r
```

I get what you'd expect in graph mode - a little graph centered on the "ddd" node.

Then I look at the graph using the 'table' mode (by clicking to the left), and there's no data:

```
r
(empty)
(empty)
```

I know the 'r' rows are not empty - I just saw their visualization. Also, if I enter a similar query into this site: http://console.neo4j.org/, I see the data I want to see.

How can I configure the stock web interface to give this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it only shows the "properties" of a relationship.

If you `RETURN type(r)` you see the rel-type

and if you `RETURN {type:type(r),id:id(r),props:r}` then you see everything as a nested map.